# cannot launch Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm getting the following failure when I try to run my jupyterbook.

```
(regen) qczhang@k8s-master01:~/MedReportGen/Medical-Report-Generation-master$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/qczhang/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/home/qczhang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .nbextensions import install_nbextension
  File "/home/qczhang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/nbextensions.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .config_manager import BaseJSONConfigManager
  File "/home/qczhang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/config_manager.py", line 13, in <module>
    from traitlets.config import LoggingConfigurable
  File "/home/qczhang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .application import *
  File "/home/qczhang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 17, in <module>
    from decorator import decorator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'decorator'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `decorator` module is not present in your environment.

You could try to install it manually ([decorator in pip](https://pypi.org/project/decorator/#description)):

```sh
pip install decorator
```